# Why does VBA ask me to choose from a macro when I'm trying to run a code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a code with VBA, but the issue is that it always ask me to choose from macros that I already have for other purposes, instead of directly running the code.

```
Sub CreerTableau()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsInitiatives As Worksheet, wsEvolutions As Worksheet, wsDashboard As Worksheet
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim feuille As String
    Dim GP As String
    Dim projet As String
    Dim tableRow As Long

    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook

    ' Spécifie les feuilles source
    Set wsInitiatives = wbSource.Sheets("Initiatives et projets")
    Set wsEvolutions = wbSource.Sheets("Evolutions")

    ' Spécifie la feuille Dashboard CIO (où se trouve le bouton de commande)
    Set wsDashboard = wbSource.Sheets("Dashboard CIO")

    ' Détermine le dernier numéro de ligne dans la colonne de statut de projet des feuilles "Initiatives et projets"
    lastRow = wsInitiatives.Cells(wsInitiatives.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    tableRow = 2
    For rowNum = 2 To lastRow 
        
        If (wsInitiatives.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = "Pas commencé" Or wsInitiatives.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = "En étude de faisabilité") And _
           wsInitiatives.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value <> "" Then
            feuille = "Initiatives et projets"
            GP = wsInitiatives.Cells(rowNum, 4).Value
            projet = wsInitiatives.Cells(rowNum, 5).Value

            CreerTableauDestination feuille, rowNum, GP, projet, tableRow
            tableRow = tableRow + 1
        End If
    Next rowNum
End sub
```

What is the solution?

I tried to change the macro names so that they're not similar but it still didn't work

Comment: `it always ask me to choose from macros that I already have` - what does that mean?

Comment: When you attempt to run the code, which button are you clicking? Or which control are you interacting with? If you're running code directly from the VBProject window, click on the macro so that your input cursor is on the macro, and then press Run. If you haven't clicked on any macro, or the code window is not active, it will not know which macro you want to run.

Comment: Adding to @Toddleson, the 'choose macro' window will also pop up if your cursor is inside a macro that requires arguments. For example, your `CreerTableauDestination` seems like it requires arguments, so you cannot run it directly, you have to pass arguments to it.

Comment: @Toddleson when I'm trying to run the code I'm clicking the green arrow that runs the sub and my code. window is active, so when i click it, a macro window pops up and it asks me to run from a list of macros that I already have.

Comment: @GSerg when i click run, a window with all my macros pos up and it asks me to choose for one.

Comment: Where is the caret when you do that?

Comment: Caret? I didn't understand what do you mean, there is no caret

Comment: *"Caret or insertion point, a blinking vertical bar indicating where typed text will be inserted when using a cursor (user interface)"* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_(disambiguation))).

Comment: There is no caret when I'm trying to click the run button, I just select all the subroutine and then click on the green arrow

Comment: There is always a caret in the code editor. And you are supposed to put it inside the method you are trying to run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.